# Frequency analysis of linestring using QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-analysis, frequency

I have a data-set that consists of linestrings across different timestamps. I want to identify the segments that occur the most frequently.

I am using R to import the data from JSON files, create spatial objects to then import into QGIS. I would prefer to do the spatial analysis using QGIS, but I am facing a few hurdles irrespective of the approach I try. These are the approaches I am trying:

1. Use another layer that contains polygons as the baseline to identify the polygons that have the most number of intersections with the linestrings. [this will help me identify polygons, but once that has been done, what will be the optimal way to identify the linestring that is most frequent within these polygon(s)]
2. Use another layer of points/lines as a base layer to identify the ones that have the linestrings close to them. [But again, I am stumbling at identifying the actual linestring]

It feels like I may able to identify zones/points in the base layer but how do I find the linestrings (or section of linestrings) that occur most frequently using QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, you can execute an SQL-query on every layer, even if it is not in an SQL-database.

Go to Database > databasemanager > virtual layers > Project layers

Open the SQL-window and add the following query (change 'your_layer' to the projectlayer in your project):

```sql
select geometry, count(geometry)
from your_layer
group by geometry
order by count(geometry) desc limit 100
```

this will return the 100 most frequently features in your layer